# Help in checking work to volume problem

Tags: integration

Alright, I've got plenty of work to show for this one.

The question goes...

Suppose $ D$ is a solid bounded below by the sphere $ x^2 + y^2 +(z-1)^2 = 1$ and above by the cone $ z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ Find the volume.

Alright, so, I'm thinking this type of problem is best solved with cylindrical coordinates, because spherical are generally messy and I can see a cylinder that we could revolve around, if you catch my drift.

So, I set up the integral as...

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{1-r^2}+1}^{r} dzrdrd\theta$$

The top limit is obvious (just plug and chug) but the bottom one might need a bit of explaining. Plugging in the typical cylindrical coordinates, I get

$$ (z-1)^2 = 1 - r^2 $$

And from there we just take the square root of both sides, and add one over.

Now, the fun part, evaluation!

So, we get...

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} r^2-r\sqrt{1-r^2}-r\,drd\theta $$

Which unfortunately provides me with an answer of $ \frac{-2\pi}{3} $ and volume can't be negative. Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: Worked out answer, with corrected limits by USER?=@HKLee

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{r} dzrdrd\theta $$

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} r^2-r+\sqrt{1-r^2} \, drd\theta $$

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} r^2-r+\sqrt{1-r^2} \, drd\theta $$

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{r^3}{3}-\frac{r^2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-r^2}}{3} \bigg|_{0}^{1} \,d\theta $$

$$ 2\pi\,(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}) $$

$$ 2\pi\,(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}) $$

$$2\pi\,(\frac{4}{6}-\frac{3}{6}) $$

$$2\pi\,(\frac{1}{6}) $$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{3} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw picture :

$$ z= 1-\sqrt{1-r^2} $$
in sphere so that $$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{1-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^r dz rdrd\theta $$

Comment: But $ x^2 + y^2 +(z-1)^2 = 1 $ does not equal your bottom limit...?

Comment: I do not understand. More clearly please ask

Comment: In sphere fix $r$ then we have two choices : $$ z=1\pm \sqrt{1-r^2} $$

Comment: Bottom bound...

$$ x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2 = 1 $$

$$ r^2 + (z-1)^2 = 1 $$ 

$$ (z-1)^2 = 1-r^2 $$

$$ z - 1 = \sqrt{1-r^2} $$

$$ z = \sqrt{1-r^2} + 1 $$

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh...now I see...thanks!

Comment: It is not complete : $z-1$ may be negative. For instance $x^2=1$ implies $x=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

A sketch can show volume as consisting of a hemisphere and cone by standard formulas but should be confirmed with triple integral evaluation.

But please check computational errors could be still be there. Results of integration are:  ($ z_1 $ is axial distance upto start of cap from center).

$$ V_{cap}= \pi (2 R^3/3 + z_1(z_1^2/3-R^2)); V_{cone}= \pi (R-z_1)(R^2-z_1^2)/3 ; $$

which still gives an erroneous result for $R=1$ as $ (2-\sqrt 2) \pi/3.$

Comment: This is incorrect, unfortunately. The correct answer is $ \frac{\pi}{3} $, for future reference.

Comment: I revised the above but still error  persists.

Comment: see worked out answer above. Not sure what you're doing.